# Which is steps of a good dissertation of master's is on-topic or off-topic?

Tags: discussion

Would like know, if this ask does part of scope community

> Would like of submit one propose of master's degree, but not know for where begin.
>
> > Someone could say which are the principles topics the one good dissertation? which are your main elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be off-topic here. The room is about how to teach CS. I would suggest https://academia.stackexchange.com as a better place. Good luck in your studies.

Comment: Ok, thanks =) 0